# Textbox(Username,Password) auto-fill off with chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cookies

In the chrome browser if I saved the username and password for the website while login then in the whole website wherever it found `Username` and `Password` field and those fields are empty then by default it assigns the Saved username and password for those fields.

I tried with autocomplete='off' and also rename those field names as `txtUN` instead of `txtUserName` and `txtPass` instead of `txtPassword` but it didn't work. 
[image]

So how to prevent the auto fill the username and Password field? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Autocomplete='off' is not working anymore. Check out post there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Comment: Yes, in the modern browsers autocomplete is no more supported, but still i tried :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the answer from mike nelson in this article

[Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

**Updated Solution**

Chrome now ignores . Therefore my original workaround (which I had deleted) is now all the rage.

Simply create a couple of fields and make them hidden with "display:none". Example:

```
<!-- fake fields are a workaround for chrome autofill getting the wrong fields -->
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered"/>
<input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out and relogging in your Google/gmail account to get an option for auto fill else check your privacy settings in preferences.

Answer (score -1):

$(document).ready(function () {
            debugger

```
        $('input[autocomplete="off"]').each(function () {
            debugger
            var input = this;
            var name = $(input).attr('name');
            var id = $(input).attr('id');

            $(input).removeAttr('name');
            $(input).removeAttr('id');

            setTimeout(function () {
                debugger
                $(input).attr('name', name);
                $(input).attr('id', id);
            }, 1);
        });
    });
```

Before this put autocomplete="off" for each field you want to.